# using compiled libs between windows compiler, cygwin and linux g++

Tags: linux, visual-studio, g++, cygwin

If I have a windows compiler based dll and .lib, can I link them with a app that I am compiling with cygwin g++ ? If not, will it work with a linux g++ library build ?

Are libraries generated from windows compiler, cygwin g++ and linux g++ cross linkable ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there are not. Libraries and executable files are specific to an operating system and to a processor. The only thing you can consider porting is source code, if it is written with great care. Some libraries (e.g. QtCore, Gtk/Glib, ...) are abstracting a platform and give you a common API (usable on many OSes), but you still have to compile for each system.

You could target a virtual machine (like JVM thru Java, or Lua bytecode, or Ocaml bytecode, ...) to get additional portability (at the expense of the cost of the VM implementation). You could also code software as scripts (e.g. using Python).

Comment: I am trying to use a external lib and they provide windows builds and linux builds of the library. So only if they provide cygwin build, I will be able to use their lib for my purpose ?

Comment: No, the compiled form of a library is operating system and machine specific. You have to provide separate builds for Windows and for Linux (even a separate build for Linux x86, Linux x86-64, Linux ARM...).

Comment: You need a cygwin build of the library (or build the library yourself from source code) to use that library under cygwin.